# "Value of property CidrIp must be of type String" cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I encountered a problem with my CFN template. I define a CIDR block in Parameters and want to use it as a `CidrIp` in a Security Group resource.

However when I run my stack I get `Value of property CidrIp must be of type String` error and the stack is being rolled back.

Here is my minimal failing template. I want to use `VPCCidrBlock` to define the `CidrIp`.

What is funny, AWSs sample tamplate `LAMP_Multi_AZ` does exactly the same thing.

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "A cloud VPC",
  "Metadata": {
  },
  "Resources": {
    "myvpc": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": {
          "Ref": "VPCCidrBlock"
        }
      }
    },
    "SipserverSecurityGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Enable VPC access",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "myvpc"
        },
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
          { "IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": "22", "ToPort": "22", "CidrIp": { "Ref": "VPCCidrBlock" } },
          { "IpProtocol": "udp", "FromPort": "5060", "ToPort": "5060", "CidrIp": { "Ref:": "VPCCidrBlock" } }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Parameters": {
    "VPCCidrBlock": {
      "Description": "Main CIDR block for the whole VPC",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "9",
      "MaxLength": "18",
      "Default": "10.13.0.0/16",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is there `"Ref:"` instead of `"Ref"`. Funny that it validates ok.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced similar issue I was able to point out the issue. I was using "ref" instead "Ref" to refer parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Strange problem. Played around with your example a little bit.

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "A cloud VPC",
  "Metadata": {
  },
  "Resources": {
    "myvpc": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": {
          "Ref": "VPCCidrBlock"
        }
      }
    },
    "SipserverSecurityGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Enable VPC access",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "myvpc"
        },
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
          { "IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": "22", "ToPort": "22", "CidrIp": {"Ref": "VPCCidrBlock"}},
          { "IpProtocol": "udp", "FromPort": "5060", "ToPort": "5060", "CidrIp": {"Ref": "VPCCidrBlock"}}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Parameters": {
    "VPCCidrBlock": {
      "Description": "Main CIDR block for the whole VPC",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "9",
      "MaxLength": "18",
      "Default": "10.13.0.0/16",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
    }
  }
}
```

Works for me. Is it possible that there is an issue with some special characters/encoding?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that we could easily overlook is datatype definition in the case of YAML configuration. In my yaml cloudformation template, I did the same mistake. I typed a dash before specifying a VpcId in my ECS ElasticLoadBalancingV2 resource configuration. That made the VpcId property look as a list of values when it should actually be a String. Inturn, I got cloudformation error that "VpcId should be a String."

Incorrect definition: (a dash at the beginning of line 5)

```
TargetGroup:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  Properties:
    VpcId:
      - Fn::ImportValue: !Join ['-', ["somestring", !Ref Environment, 'someregion', 'VPC']]
```

Correct definition:

```
TargetGroup:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  Properties:
    VpcId: Fn::ImportValue: !Join ['-', ["somestring", !Ref Environment, 'someregion', 'VPC']]
```

Comment: it's giving "mapping values are not allowed here" error

Comment: Targets:
          - Arn: 'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${StackName}-LambdaArn'
            Id: "LambdaFunctionV1"
            RetryPolicy:
              MaximumRetryAttempts: 0

Answer (score 0):

I had another YAML file got the same issue "Value of property CidrIp must be of type String”. It turns out that double quote below need to be changed to a single quote.

```
HTTPTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${Foo}-${Bar}-TargetGroup" # -> Error
      Name: !Sub '${Foo}-${Bar}-TargetGroup' # -> Good
```